# How can I enable Boxcutter addon HUD display for dimension while drawing?

Tags: add-on

How can I enable Boxcutter addon HUD display for dimension while drawing?

[image]

how can I enable this?

I looked everywhere and couldn't find the option.

Comment: It's an external addon, not part of Blender so you'll have to ask the addon author.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Hard Ops > Ui > Operator UI options > Boxcutter Notification*.